# rust clap parse ipv4Addr

Tags: rust, clap

I want to use the clap derive API in order to parse an `Ipv4Addr`.

```rust
#![allow(unused)]
use clap; // 3.1.6
use clap::Parser;
use std::net::Ipv4Addr;

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[clap(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
struct Args {
    
    #[clap(short, long, parse(from_str))]
    ip_dst: Ipv4Addr,

}

fn main() {
    let args = Args::parse();
}
```

My attempt gives the following error even though Ipv4Addr seems to implement `FromStr` which provides `from_str`

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Ipv4Addr: From<&str>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:10:31
   |
10 |     #[clap(short, long, parse(from_str))]
   |                               ^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<&str>` is not implemented for `Ipv4Addr`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <Ipv4Addr as From<[u8; 4]>>
             <Ipv4Addr as From<u32>>

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

My Questions are:

- Why isn't the method provided by `FromStr` used?
- How can I fix the program to do what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is what is used by default (since `Ipv4Addr` implements [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/struct.Ipv4Addr.html#impl-FromStr)), without specifiying any `parse` option:

```rust
use clap; // 3.1.6
use clap::Parser;
use std::net::Ipv4Addr;

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[clap(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
struct Args {
    #[clap(short, long)]
    ip_dst: Ipv4Addr,
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=42b70ffb69d2104f7905fe22bd30901a)

Otherwise, you need to use `try_from_str` as per the example:

```rust
#![allow(unused)]
use clap; // 3.1.6
use clap::Parser;
use std::net::Ipv4Addr;

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[clap(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
struct Args {
    
    #[clap(short, long, parse(try_from_str))]
    ip_dst: Ipv4Addr,

}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=532300de008b6b0ec782a28dac81b576)

Comment: the second playground has an issue (which I also have locally). I suspect it is because not version of clap is 4.0 and not 3.1. The errors are that the `method parse found for struct must have a self parameter`. The second error is about the `try_from_str` that is not in this scope.

Comment: Instead, it seems that one solution is to use `value_parser`. Some information is available here https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/_cookbook/typed_derive/index.html

Answer (score 3):

`Ipv4Addr` implements [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/str/trait.FromStr.html) but not `From<&str>` which is the [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.From.html) trait with `&str` as a parameter. If you want to use `FromStr`, specify `parse(try_from_str)` or omit it since [it's the default](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap/blob/v3.1.6/examples/derive_ref/README.md#arg-types).

Answer (score 2):

Update for Clap v4

```
use clap::{arg, value_parser, Command}; // Clap v4
use std::net::Ipv4Addr;

fn main() {
    let matches = Command::new("clap-test")
        .arg(
            arg!(--ip <VALUE>)
                .default_value("127.0.0.1")
                .value_parser(value_parser!(Ipv4Addr)),
        )
        .get_matches();

    println!(
        "IP {:?}",
        matches.get_one::<Ipv4Addr>("ip").expect("required"),
    );
}
```